# How to Spring Boot app run on weblogic 12C?

Tags: java, weblogic

How to Spring Boot app run on weblogic 12c.

My application class like this :

```
package com.website;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@MapperScan("com.website.mapper")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactoryBean() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());

        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        sessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations(resolver.getResources("classpath:/mybatis/*.xml"));
        return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    /**
     * Start
     * 
     * @Created by zyj on 2016年11月28日
     * @param args
     * @Version 1.0
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now, I deploy app on weblogic.

It shows the deployment success.

However, there are no Spring Boot log messages in the console.

My controller is configured with a mapping `@RequestMapping("/home/sign_in")`.

When i visit `http://localhost:7001/demo/home/sign_in`, I got `404`.

Console without any changes.

I want to run Spring Boot applications on Weblogic how to do?

I need help. Thank you very much.

PS :

This is part of my `pom.xml` file :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.smember</groupId>
<artifactId>website</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>website Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
...
<build>
    <finalName>website</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: You can package your app as a WAR and use JNDI resources: https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Comment: I changed my question, Please look at the end , It's my `pom.xml` file content.

Answer (score 1):

Add Weblogic.xml and dispatcher-servlet [empty] in Web_INF.
Also for datasource configuration, define it in weblogic and use the JNDI name here [see below]

In application.properties
 spring.datasource.jndi-name=xyz-jndi-name

**weblogic.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd                         http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app                         http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.1</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>bh</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name> 
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic expects WAR package.
You should change your packaging to WAR instead of JAR by modifying your pom.xml.

Comment: I was deploying WAR.